# How to make images for different screen sizes?

Tags: android, android-layout, resolution, device

Getting my head around Android, I've sort of trouble understanding support for multiple 
devices. I've gone through the dev-docu, now for the clear-up:

The idea behind using dp is, that e.g. a button has the same 'real-world'-size, independent of the actual screen-size, right?
If so, that means, I provide the images in ldpi, hdpi and so on. That results in a button, that has always the same size.
If still correct, I understand that now, that my buttons always has the same size, I should provide different layouts, because on a small device, there might only be space for two next to one another, where on a larger device there's room for three.

If all of the above is correct, my question would be, how I deal graphics-tool-wise with it. Say I have a button 100px x 100px at 300dpi, what sizes and dpi's would that be for the new documents in e.g. Gimp for the different screensizes?

Thanx in advance for any smoke-lifting!
Marcus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more study, it seems that the graphocs-tools DPI are actually the one referred to in e.g. the baseline. So to create a baseline-doc, you indeed create a document 470 x 320 pixel in size and a resolution of 160 dpi. The rest goes from there.

Answer (score 0):

What it means when you can use your custom assets for different screen densities is that when you put those respective assets, they will not scale again and use them as they are. Now it is true that the size of the screen also varies. That is when you can consider tweaking your layout.

For example in a large screen you may be able to fit two components beside each other and use a linear layout with horizontal alignment. But when it comes to a small screen, that might not be possible and one option is to define a new layout for small screens and say pt those two components in a vertical layout.

For more information regarding how to implement this and best practices, check [these Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: sorry, but that still doesn't ring a bell how to set up the graphics. how relate dpi and size of an image to hdpi... and layout-size?

Comment: Did you go through the docs? I have added the link in my reply and everything explained in detail there. But in short you are looking for how they are calculating the image ratios for each density. It is 3:4:6:8 for ldpi:mdpi:hdpi:xhdpi. Now they are not exact but they will be close. That and how to provide different layouts for different screen sizes is explained in the documentation for which I provided the link above.

Comment: jip, actually twice allready, but I don't get how to start. so, for a backgroundImage e.g. I'd start with an image of 470 x 320 pixel in size and a resolution of 160 dpi, because those are the normal baseline values?